# Swift overriding protocol extension keeping the extension behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, protocols

I have this simple class and an hypothetical protocol called 'ShowAlert', it's extension to do the default implementation and a default ViewController and it's ShowAlert protocol implementation.

```
protocol ShowAlert {
    var titleForAlert: String! { get }
    func messageForAlert() -> String!
    func show()
}

extension ShowAlert where Self: UIViewController {

    func show(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: self.titleForAlert, message: self.messageForAlert(), preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func showItNow(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.show()
    }



}

extension ViewController: ShowAlert {
    var titleForAlert: String! {
        get{
            return "Foo"
        }
    }


    func messageForAlert() -> String! {
        return "Bar"
    }

    func show() {
    // here I want to call the default implementation of the protocol to show the alert, then do something else
        print("Good day sir!")
    }
}
```

It's like on a subclass where I could call a 'super.show()' and then continue implementing whatever I want to do after that.

There's any way to do it? Or my logic go against what protocols are design for and that don't suppose to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple solution: Just add a `defaultShow` method to the extension.

```
extension ShowAlert where Self: UIViewController {

    func defaultShow(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: self.titleForAlert, message: self.messageForAlert(), preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func show() {
        defaultShow()
    }
}
```

So in your code you can just call `defaultShow`:

```
extension ViewController: ShowAlert {
    // ...

    func show() {
        self.defaultShow()
        print("Good day sir!")
    }
}
```

There is also another solution where you can call `.show()` instead of `.defaultShow()`. However it uses casting and breaks encapsulation. If you want to see it let me know.

Comment: Good idea, but I was thinking in something that Swift had something to deal with these kind of situations, without adding a new function. Thanks anyway.